# I need some help implementing eager loading

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

I've recently been tipped off to eager loading and its necessity in improving performance. I've managed to cut a few queries from loading this page, but I suspect that I can trim them down significantly more if I can eager-load the needed records correctly.

This controller needs to load all of the following to fill the view:

- A Student
- The seminar (class) page that the student is viewing
- All of the objectives included in that seminar
- The objective_seminars, the join table between objectives and seminars. This includes the column "priority" which is set by the teacher and used in ordering the objectives.
- The objective_students, another join table. Includes a column "points" for the student's score on that objective.
- The seminar_students, one last join table. Includes some settings that the student can adjust.

Controller:

```
def student_view
    @student = Student.includes(:objective_students).find(params[:student])
    @seminar = Seminar.includes(:objective_seminars).find(params[:id])
    @oss = @seminar.objective_seminars.includes(:objective).order(:priority)
    @objectives = @seminar.objectives.order(:name)
    objective_ids = @objectives.map(&:id)
    @student_scores = @student.objective_students.where(:objective_id => objective_ids)
    @ss = @student.seminar_students.find_by(:seminar => @seminar)
    @teacher = @seminar.user

    @teach_options = teach_options(@student, @seminar, 5)
    @learn_options = learn_options(@student, @seminar, 5)
end
```

The method below is where a lot of duplicate queries are occurring that I thought were supposed to be eliminated by eager loading. This method gives the student six options so she can choose one objective to teach her classmates. The method looks first at objectives where the student has scored between 75% and 99%. Within that bracket, they are also sorted by "priority" (from the objective_seminars join table. This value is set by the teacher.) If there is room for more, then the method looks at objectives where the student has scored 100%, sorted by priority. (The learn_options method is practically the same as this method, but with different bracket numbers.)

teach_options method:

```
def teach_options(student, seminar, list_limit)
        teach_opt_array = []
        [[70,99],[100,100]].each do |n|
            @oss.each do |os|
                obj = os.objective
                this_score = @student_scores.find_by(:objective => obj)
                if this_score
                    this_points = this_score.points
                    teach_opt_array.push(obj) if (this_points >= n[0] && this_points <= n[1])
                end
            end
            break if teach_opt_array.length > list_limit
        end
        return teach_opt_array
    end
```

Thank you in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jeff - In regards to your question, I don't see where a lot of queries would be happening outside of `@student_scores.find_by(:objective => obj)`. 
Your `@student_scores` object is already an ActiveRecord relation, correct? So you can use `.where()` on this, or `.select{}` without hitting the db again. Select will leave you with an array though, rather than an AR Relation, so be careful there.

```
this_score = @student_scores.where(objectve: obj)
this_score = @student_scores.select{|score| score.objective == obj}
```

Those should work.

Just some other suggestions on your top controller method - I don't see any guards or defensive coding, so if any of those objects are nil, your `.order(:blah)` is probably going to error out. Additionally, if they return nil, your subsequent queries which rely on their data could error out. I'd opt for some `try()`s or rescues.

Last, just being nitpicky, but those first two lines are a little hard to read, in that you could mistakenly interpret the params as being applied to the includes as well as the main object:

```
@student = Student.includes(:objective_students).find(params[:student])
@seminar = Seminar.includes(:objective_seminars).find(params[:id])
```

I'd put the find with your main object, followed by the includes:

```
@student = Student.find(params[:student]).includes(:objective_students)
@seminar = Seminar.find(params[:id]).includes(:objective_seminars)
```

Comment: Are you saying that "where" doesn't send another hit to the db, but "find_by" does? If so, that makes sense.  Also, the syntax with the "includes" at the end of the chain was the way I tried it first. It kicked up an error that way.